# Flatten array, but using sub-array as basis

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, transformation, ramda.js

We are trying to take an array that has this format:

```
[
{batchId: 123, files: [{fileName: 'fileA.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileB.txt'}],
{batchId: 456, files: [{fileName: 'fileC.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileD.txt'}],
]
```

and flatten it so it is expressed as:

```
[
{batchId: 123, fileName: 'fileA.txt'},
{batchId: 123, fileName: 'fileB.txt'},
{batchId: 456, fileName: 'fileC.txt'},
{batchId: 456, fileName: 'fileD.txt'},
]
```

We are hoping that there is a more elegant way to transform this data using pre-existing library such as Ramda or Lodash, however any javascript implementation would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce()` and `map()` methods and return new array.

```js
const data = [
{batchId: 123, files: [{fileName: 'fileA.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileB.txt'}]},
{batchId: 456, files: [{fileName: 'fileC.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileD.txt'}]},
]

const result = data.reduce((r, e) => {
  r.push(...e.files.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, {batchId: e.batchId})))
  return r;
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you can use nested [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) calls and flatten the resulting sub-arrays by [spreading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) into [`Array.concat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```js
const data = [{batchId: 123, files: [{fileName: 'fileA.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileB.txt'}]},{batchId: 456, files: [{fileName: 'fileC.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileD.txt'}]}];

const result = [].concat(...
  data.map(({ batchId, files }) => 
    files.map(({ fileName }) => ({ batchId, fileName })
  )));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = [
    {batchId: 123, files: [{fileName: 'fileA.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileB.txt'}]},
    {batchId: 456, files: [{fileName: 'fileC.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileD.txt'}]},
];

function flatten(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(newArray, item) {
      return newArray.concat(item.files.map(function(file) { 
          return {
             batchId: item.batchId,
             fileName: file.fileName
          };
     }));
  }, []);
}

console.log(flatten(arr));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to this is to use [`R.chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain), which effectively maps the provided function over the list to produce a list of lists and then flattens the result.

```js
const data =
  [ {batchId: 123, files: [{fileName: 'fileA.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileB.txt'}]}
  , {batchId: 456, files: [{fileName: 'fileC.txt'}, {fileName: 'fileD.txt'}]}
  ]

const fn =
  R.chain(({batchId, files}) => R.map(R.assoc('batchId', batchId), files))

console.log(fn(data))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

At some point in the future you will likely be able to make use of the [proposed](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-flatMap/#sec-Array.prototype.flatMap) [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) instead of `R.chain`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), the [`spread operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) you can achieve your required result.

**DEMO**

```js
const arr = [{
  batchId: 123,
  files: [{
    fileName: 'fileA.txt'
  }, {
    fileName: 'fileB.txt'
  }]
}, {
  batchId: 456,
  files: [{
    fileName: 'fileC.txt'
  }, {
    fileName: 'fileD.txt'
  }]
}];


let result = arr.reduce((r, o) => {
  return [...r, ...o.files.map(v => {
    return Object.assign(v, {
      batchId: o.batchId
    });
  })];
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```